# Does WhatsApp Web Require Phone on Wifi

Tags: whatsapp

Does WhatsApp web require the computer and phone to be connected to the same wifi network simultaneously?

Assume I've already authenticated and used WhatsApp web - then taken my phone outside the house (miles away, no chance of it still being connected to WiFi). Now I log back into WhatsApp web, would it still work?

Reason I ask is that I've lost my phone and yet WhatsApp web was still working (until the phone died). So I'm wondering whether it's actually lost (outside the house - many miles away) or whether it's actually hiding in the house somewhere and was actually still connected to the WiFi network (until it died).

Answer (score 1):

No.

I've successfully used it whilst my laptop was connected to home WiFi whilst mobile was connected to mobile data.  It wasted more data but it still worked.